# trying to make a breadcrum header for multistep form for mobile device

Tags: css, html, psd

I am trying to make header for multistage form like the image shown bellow

[image]

The **CSS** for the code is as follow 3.

```
.checkout-tabs {
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    border-top: 1px solid #C4C4C4;*/
}
.checkout-tabs li {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
}
.checkout-tabs .stage-payment, .checkout-tabs .stage-delivery {
    text-indent: 15px;
}
.checkout-tabs .status-flag {
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 16px;
}
.checkout-tabs .disabled {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F0F0F0;
    color: #AAAAAA;
}
.checkout-tabs .disabled .status-flag {
    background-color: #C6C6C6;
    color: #D8D8D8;
}
.checkout-tabs .done {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FAFAFA;
    color: #252525;
}
.checkout-tabs .done .status-flag {
    background-color: #2D8E24;
    color: #FAFAFA;
}
.checkout-tabs .active {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFE274;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.checkout-tabs .active .status-flag {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.checkout-tabs .stage-login:before, .checkout-tabs .stage-delivery:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #C4C4C4;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 15px;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: -31px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.checkout-tabs .stage-login:after, .checkout-tabs .stage-delivery:after {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #0000FF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 15px;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
.checkout-tabs .stage-login.disabled:after, .checkout-tabs .stage-delivery.disabled:after {
    border-left-color: #F0F0F0;
}
.checkout-tabs .stage-login.active:after, .checkout-tabs .stage-delivery.active:after {
    border-left-color: #FFE274;
}
.checkout-tabs .stage-login.done:after, .checkout-tabs .stage-delivery.done:after {
    border-left-color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

And the **HTML** is something like this

```
<ul class="cf checkout-tabs" style="list-style:none">
    <li class="active talign-center stage-login"></li>
    <li class="disabled talign-center stage-delivery"></li>
    <li class="disabled talign-center stage-delivery"></li>
    <li class="disabled talign-center  stage-delivery"></li>
    <li class="disabled talign-center  stage-payment "></li>
</ul>
```

Would be great if any one could help me out to make this design better .

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/U9sW7/4/)

Comment: And what is the problem? What is the question exactly?

Comment: trying to improve the design bro . If you look into the fiddle it does not look good .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the demo which I tried to design

Please have a look

```
<div data-role="page" id="wizard">
    <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Wizard</h1>

    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="">
            <ul class="cf checkout-tabs" style="list-style:none">
                <li class="active1 talign-center stage-login" style="">1</li>
                <li class="disabled talign-center stage-delivery">2</li>
                <li class="disabled talign-center stage-delivery">3</li>
                <li class="disabled talign-center  stage-delivery">4</li>
                <li class="disabled talign-center  stage-payment ">5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="steps">
            <div class="step">
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
                    <h3>Step 1</h3>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">

<h3>Step 2</h3>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">

<h3>Step 3</h3>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">

<h3>Step 4</h3>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">

<h3>Step 5</h3>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Wizard</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

**[**Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/ZzCA2/71/)****